# Passing expressions to be evaluated within a go application?

Tags: go, lua, eval

I have a go command line application, that has a search function to scan a list of objects (structs). I want to be able to invoke that search function, i.e. instead of just

```
mycmd search bob
```

Perhaps I can do:

```
mycmd search 'o.Name() == "bob"'
mycmd search 'len(o.PhoneNumbers()) > 1'
mycmd search 'strings.Index(o.Name(), "bob") >= 0'
```

Is it possible to process an expression like this, within a loop in your `go` code? If this is not possible, what is the simplest and most standard way to approach this in GO, without creating my own expression language/evaluator?

(I can see we have things like `go-v8` and `golua`, however I'm not sure if this is the right way to think about it?)

**NOTE:** its a personal script, security concerns are out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the [`text.template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package for the evaluation of your input.
And later parse the output of it for the result of the entered expression.

This is was a few Go build tools do. For example `docker inspect` uses this for formatting its output.

Comment: I think this is an excellent solution in the case where the expressions required are rather simple. This may well be the answer for some problems. However, the template language doesn't support much more than simple comparison statements. (string manipulation and things like that are not possible)

Comment: @Jacob You can inject custom function into the template context for more complicated stuff.

Comment: True, but then you would have to create a whole suite of functions—predicting which sort of things a user creating an expression might want to use.  (i.e. How much of the go "strings" package would you need to wrap up and expose?) Could work, but it won't in my case.